# Win this poker game

Tags: probability, markov-chains

52 poker cards (half red and half black). Every time you draw a card, if you draw  a red card, then you win one dollar. 
If you draw black card, then you lose one dollar.

Say you start with $n$ dollars, if you can stop/quit this game anytime you want, how much are you willing to pay this game?

What would be your optimal play strategy?

---

Attempt:

I think this is very similar to the gambler's ruin problem; We can let each state denote the amount of money that the gambler has. However, the transistion probability would be dependent/varied from state to state.

Comment: Do you put back the card into the 52 card piles after u draw it?

Comment: if I can put it back, then it will become gambler's ruin problem. Let us assume that's the case. Even with this assumption, I still have trouble to figure out "how much you are willing to pay for this game", if we can stop anytime we want.

Comment: what does this have to do with markov chains/processes ?

Comment: stopping when $R < B - \sqrt(B)$ seems to be pretty close to the optimal strategy.

Comment: "Let us assume that's the case" ?? The question is interesting when one does not put back the cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: First consider a deck containing only 6 cards, 3 +ve & 3 -ve (where + is for red and -ve is for black). Then generalize it for 52 cards.

I think you should take a lot at this page [52 Cards Win a Dollar](http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/fourteen.htm).

Comment: Maybe this should be a comment.